# Does any have a repository of improperly formatted RSS feeds

Tags: rss

I just implemented a version of [Peter Bromberg's](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9faa101f-0a1a-465f-a41a-3e52dd9f7526/everything-rss--atom-feed-parser.aspx) RSS feed parser. Now, **I need samples of improperly formatted RSS feeds from all versions (0.91, 0.92, 1.0, 2.0) so I can test the code in real-word conditions**. Does anyone know any or a site with many improperly formatted RSS feeds or know a repository of improperly-formatted RSS feeds?

Comment: LOL, to anybody who suggests that you create your own, I would say: you need real world examples containing defects you would not have thought of creating.

Comment: @DOK, exactly. Plus, I cannot handle coded-examples to the tester/QA guy.

Comment: You have testers?! Hey, let them find the test data.

Comment: @DOK: Well, easier said than done. I need the bad rss myself to make sure my code work. Unit test with controlled conditions only go so far. Plus, the testers are smart people but not developers. If I tell them to go find a rss with a relative URL path or an invalid rss tag (like html <em> tag)... That wouldn't sit well. And they are no going to run my unit test. Thanks for the question.

Comment: I suppose you could think of a different way to solve your problem here. Perhaps ask how other people test their RSS feed readers. Somebody is testing this stuff, maybe using a different approach from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some information-gathering; the best way to do this is to do a search with your favorite search engine and try to find some site that support multiple RSS-types. Putting double quotes around the rss types (e.g. "rss 0.92") helps a lot.